Azure Devops Pipeline how to dynamically make (mutually exclusive) stage skipped
I have both B & C stage depends on A, and B & C are supposed to be mutually exclusive stage.
Let's say Stage B contains rollback task and C contains deploy task. When stage C is approved and completed, ideally I would like stage B automatically marks as skipped so the entire pipeline can be considered as completed and no other devs can execute this again.
I tried many different ways, but none of them worked as I expected.
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    steps:
    - checkout: none    
    - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one;isOutput=true]secondValue"
      name: setOne      
    - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageVal;isOutput=true]this is a stage output variable"
      name: MyOutputVar      
- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  condition: not(succeeded('C'))
  jobs:
  - deployment: JobB
    environment: 'Integration'
    variables: 
      myvar: $[stageDependencies.C.JobC.outputs['skipstep.skipsubsequent']]
      myvar2: $[stageDependencies.A.JobA.outputs['setOne.one']]
      myStageAVar: $[stageDependencies.A.JobA.outputs['MyOutputVar.myStageVal']]
    strategy: 
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none 
          - bash: echo $(myStageAVar)         
          - bash: echo "$(myvar), $(myvar2)"
            displayName: 'Run a one-line script B'            
- stage: C
  dependsOn: A
  condition: not(succeeded('B'))
  jobs:
  - deployment: JobC
    condition: not(succeeded('B'))
    environment: 'Integration'    
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none
          - bash: |
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipsubsequent;isOutput=true]true"
            name: skipstep   




please can you provide minimum reproducible code?

updated with pipeline sample code

let see what happens I have provided a modified code.

update the code let me know if that works!

Also be interest about this topic. any progress, seems not easy to achieve via a first-galance-elegant way.

@wenbo, seems easy at first glance, but I couldn't achieve the desired outcome

You are almost there, I think the problem might be the logic, which is understandable,for Stage C you need to sets an output variable skipB to true after it has successful completed.
After which Stage B now checks whether the skipB variable is set to true. If it is, Stage B will be skipped.
For reference sake docs
I have modified the code you provided.
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=stageACompleted;isOutput=true]true"
      name: setStageACompleted

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  condition: and(succeeded('A'), eq(variables['stageACompleted'], 'true'), eq(variables['stageBApproved'], 'true'))
  jobs:
  - job: JobB
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - bash: echo "Rollback task"

- stage: C
  dependsOn: A
  condition: and(succeeded('A'), eq(variables['stageACompleted'], 'true'), eq(variables['stageCApproved'], 'true'))


I could not get variable working as I thought you can only reference the value when the stage is in dependsOn list which I could not

@Vincent I see what you mean

Thanks Derek, the value doesn't really matter. I want stage B and C mutually exclusive, one complete should make the other either skipped or not perform anything

@Vincent I have updated the code let's see what happens.

I could not use parameter for this as user won't know the action when execute the pipeline

this becomes quite complex quickly, let me have think.

The scenarios is Stage A will deploy to azure web app slot, and depends on the outcome of slot status, user will decide run Stage B or C.


My real issue is how to manage B and C mutually exclusive relationship
Whenever B is executed, C should be skipped or not allow to be executed and vice verses.

According to your comment, what you need is to only run one stage in the stage B and stage C. In this case, you can consider disapproving another stage when running one of them using the Azure DevOps REST API Approvals - Update.
Here are the steps:

Create a personal access token with the build Read & execute permission scope.

Set a secret variable named PAT with the token you just created.


Use the following sample YAML to reject the pending approval for another stage.


trigger: none

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    steps:
    - checkout: none    

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - deployment: JobB
    environment: 'Integration'
    strategy: 
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none 
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Replace with your organization name and project name
                $organization = ""
                $project = ""
                $token="$(PAT)"
                
                # Headers
                $headers = @{
                    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$token"))
                }
                
                # Get the list of approvals
                $approvalsUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
                $approvalsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approvalsUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
                
                # Filter the pending approval for the current pipelineId
                $approval = $approvalsResponse.value | Where-Object { $_.pipeline.owner.id -eq $(Build.BuildId) -and $_.status -eq "pending" }
                
                
                if ($approval) {
                    $approvalId = $approval.id
                    # rejected the pending approval
                    $approveUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
                
                    $body = @"
                [
                  {
                    "approvalId": "$approvalId",
                    "comment": "rejected when another stage is running",
                    "status": "rejected"
                  }
                ]
                "@
                    $patchHeaders = @{
                        Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$token"))
                        "Content-Type" = "application/json"
                    }
                    $approveResponse =""
                    $approveResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approveUrl -Method Patch -Headers $patchHeaders -Body $body
                
                    # Output the response
                    $approveResponse | ConvertTO-Json
                
                } else {
                    Write-Output "No pending approval found for the pipeline."
                }

- stage: C
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - deployment: JobC
    environment: 'Integration'    
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Replace with your organization name and project name
                $organization = ""
                $project = ""
                $token="$(PAT)"
                
                # Headers
                $headers = @{
                    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$token"))
                }
                
                # Get the list of approvals
                $approvalsUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
                $approvalsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approvalsUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
                
                # Filter the pending approval for the current pipelineId
                $approval = $approvalsResponse.value | Where-Object { $_.pipeline.owner.id -eq $(Build.BuildId) -and $_.status -eq "pending" }
                
                
                if ($approval) {
                    $approvalId = $approval.id
                    # rejected the pending approval
                    $approveUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
                
                    $body = @"
                [
                  {
                    "approvalId": "$approvalId",
                    "comment": "rejected another stage",
                    "status": "rejected"
                  }
                ]
                "@
                    $patchHeaders = @{
                        Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$token"))
                        "Content-Type" = "application/json"
                    }
                    $approveResponse =""
                    $approveResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approveUrl -Method Patch -Headers $patchHeaders -Body $body
                
                    # Output the response
                    $approveResponse | ConvertTO-Json
                
                } else {
                    Write-Output "No pending approval found for the pipeline."
                }



Test result: When one stage is approved and running, another stage will be rejected.



However, as you can see there will be a Retry Stage button as the stage is marked failed not skipped. You can consider only give the required users the queue builds permission to avoid someone rerun it by mistaken.

Update:

Vincent said no variables are allowed.

As no variables are allowed, you can use the $(System.AccessToken) in the PowerShell script to send the get and patch REST API command instead of using the personal access token as secret variable.
This way, we need to add your build service account to the approval as Approver. There are two kinds of the build service account, one is project level named {Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name}), another is the organization level named Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName}). You can confirm your build service account here.

The updated YAML without using variable:
trigger: none

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    steps:
    - checkout: none    

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - deployment: JobB
    environment: 'Integration'
    strategy: 
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none 
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Replace with your organization name and project name
                $organization = ""
                $project = ""
                
                # Get the list of approvals
                $approvalsUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
                $approvalsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approvalsUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} 
                
                # Filter the pending approval for the current pipelineId
                $approval = $approvalsResponse.value | Where-Object { $_.pipeline.owner.id -eq $(Build.BuildId) -and $_.status -eq "pending" }
                
                if ($approval) {
                    $approvalId = $approval.id
                    $approvalId
                    # rejected the pending approval
                    $approveUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
                
                    $body = @"
                [
                  {
                    "approvalId": "$approvalId",
                    "comment": "rejected when another stage is running",
                    "status": "rejected"
                  }
                ]
                "@
                    $approveResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approveUrl -Method Patch -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Body $Body -ContentType application/json
                
                    # Output the response
                    $approveResponse | ConvertTO-Json
                
                } else {
                    Write-Output "No pending approval found for the pipeline."
                }

- stage: C
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - deployment: JobC
    environment: 'Integration'    
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Replace with your organization name and project name
                $organization = ""
                $project = ""
                
                # Get the list of approvals
                $approvalsUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
                $approvalsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approvalsUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} 
                
                # Filter the pending approval for the current pipelineId
                $approval = $approvalsResponse.value | Where-Object { $_.pipeline.owner.id -eq $(Build.BuildId) -and $_.status -eq "pending" }
                
                if ($approval) {
                    $approvalId = $approval.id
                    $approvalId
                    # rejected the pending approval
                    $approveUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
                
                    $body = @"
                [
                  {
                    "approvalId": "$approvalId",
                    "comment": "rejected when another stage is running",
                    "status": "rejected"
                  }
                ]
                "@
                    $approveResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approveUrl -Method Patch -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Body $Body -ContentType application/json
                
                    # Output the response
                    $approveResponse | ConvertTO-Json
                
                } else {
                    Write-Output "No pending approval found for the pipeline."
                }

Update 2:

I can't see in the approval API how can I filter the only pending stage for each pair of stages

In my PowerShell script, I used the following command to filter the only pending stage for current pipeline Id. When one of each pair of stages are running, there will only one pending stage in the current pipeline.
# This can get all approvals
approvalsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approvalsUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} 

# Filter the pending approval for the current pipeline Id
$approval = $approvalsResponse.value | Where-Object { $_.pipeline.owner.id -eq $(Build.BuildId) -and $_.status -eq "pending" }

The $approval value will be something like the following one:
{
  "id": "xxxxxxxx-5f84-4b06-xxxx-1f77bcf6642e",
  "steps": [],
  "status": "pending",
  "createdOn": "2024-08-15T02:13:13.247Z",
  "lastModifiedOn": "2024-08-15T02:13:13.246162Z",
  "executionOrder": "anyOrder",
  "minRequiredApprovers": 1,
  "blockedApprovers": [],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/xxxxxxxx-bb44-4c46-xxxx-0452cc56b07e/_apis/pipelines/approvals/xxxxxxxxx-5f84-4b06-xxxx-1f77bcf6642e"
    }
  },
  "pipeline": {
    "owner": {
      "_links": "@{web=; self=}",
      "id": 986,
      "name": "20240815.3"
    },
    "id": "104",
    "name": "test pipeline"
  }
}

Test result for each pair of stages:




unfortunately Vincent said no variables are allowed... I am still in shock.

Hi @DerekRoberts, thanks for your reminder. I updated the answer with the way that using the $(System.AccessToken) in the PowerShell script instead of using the personal access token as secret variable.

Hi @miao-tian-msft seems to me we are still using variables System.AccessToken is a special variable that carries the security token used by the running build cc: ref anyways let see what Vincent thinks nicely done.

Thanks for the approach and great details. I feel I'm falling down the rabbit hole now. I found similar approach from another post to use API to update the stage status, however this approach doesn't seem working with my scenario when I expand to have another stage. I have updated my original post to include another screenshot.

In the updated screenshot, I have added friendly displayname for each stage, and I hope it can help people to understand better what I want to achieve. I have 3 release stages that represent to 3 environments releases. At each stage, when approver approves the complete stage, the next a pair of stages (complete and rollback) are enabled and meantime I would like to automatically invalid the rollback stage, so no one would accidently rollback the release.  I hope this makes sense. I can't see in the approval api how can I filter the only pending stage for each pair of stages

Hi @Vincent, in my PowerShell script, I used some PowerShell command to filter the only pending stage for current pipeline Id. Please check the update 2 part in my answer for more details.
